# MySQL8 Restore from Physical Files - Innodb

Tags: mysql, database, backup, innodb, restore

I recently had one of my VM's go down (MS Server 2016) and the only version I am able to get up and running is two weeks old. However, I do have a backup of my C:/ drive from last night that has my `C:/ProgramData/MySQL` and `C:/Program Files/MySQL` in order to restore my databases can I simply shut down MySQL service, copy/replace the folders in my VM, and start MySQL again?

**[SOLVED] As stated in the comment below:**

Copying the entire `C:/ProgramData/MySQL` folder did not work for me, the MySQL service would not start. Instead, copying just the contents of `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data` solved the problem. The service started with no errors and all my data was recovered.

Comment: The people on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ probably know more about this than we do.

Comment: If you have the whole tree, then it should work.

Comment: I have both complete folders, should I copy them both over or just the ProgramData (that contains the table data files) over?